# insertBefore div on small screens and insertAfter on large screens

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

In my example I'm trying to insert the Small Div above the Large Div on large screens only. Then on window resize I want to insert the same Small Div bellow the Medium Div on small screens only.
The problem is that everytime I resize the window the Small Div keeps being added over and over and I want it to be added only once.

Please note that I'm looking for a JS or jQuery solution.

Regards.

```js
var smallDiv = '<div class="small">Small Div</div>';

function moveDiv() {
  if ($(window).width() < 800) {
    $(smallDiv).insertBefore(".large");
  } else {
    $(smallDiv).insertAfter(".medium");
  }
}
moveDiv();
$(window).resize(moveDiv);

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```css
.large {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: darkgray;
}

.medium {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: goldenrod;
}

.small {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="large">Large Div</div>
<div class="medium">Medium Div</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Renlado's answers is missing part of the question. You can use flex-box as suggested and order elements using order property.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.container>div {
  order: 1
}

.container>.small {
  order: 0;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .container .small {
    order: 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="large">Large Div</div>
  <div class="medium">Medium Div</div>
  <div class="small">Small Div</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a jQuery fan so lets do it with CSS

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .container {
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="large">Large Div</div>
  <div class="medium">Medium Div</div>
</div>
```